# How can you search using drive#property keys/values?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm researching if Google drive might be an appropriate platform for us to host a resource library for a web application we are building.  I would like to know if the new(?) file properties are programmatically searchable yet - didn't see any examples in the search section here: https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not searchable, yet, sorry. This feature will be coming soon. Google agree that this would be an awesome and required feature to make the new properties feature fully effective.vg

Comment: Any update on this or is there a better place to find out than here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but if anyone comes across this, Google Drive does support searching properties and appProperties for files now. See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).